# Custom Model Attributes not being passed to template

Tags: django

I have a custom user model and have my settings.AUTH pointing to my custom model, 'Profile'. I am trying to display a page that will pick one of my Profile objects and randomly display them. Then, my user will be able to choose like or dislike. But I'm stuck at simply getting them to display. As I'm just getting a page that shows 'BIO' without the user's bio, nor the users photo. The logic in views.py is getting me to the template, but the info I need isn't showing up. 
And on top of that, every time I go to this link, the current logged in user is being changed to a different user! So not sure what's going on there either, but I believe something is wrong with my logic.

**template.html**

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}


{% block content %}

<div class="tindero">
    {% if user %}
        <div class="container content is-child box column is-4 is-offset-4">
            <img src="{{ profile.photo.url  }}">
            <p style="font-size: 25px">{{profile.username}}</p>

            <b>Bio:</b>
            <p>{{profile.description}}</p>

        </div>
    {% else %}
        <p>Wait for more people to join!</p>
        <p>Help us get more user. Share this link to your friends! <a href="http://localhost:8000/">http://localhost:8000/</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def mingle(request):




    try:
        user = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        user = None
        print(Profile.username)
    try:

        description = request.user.description
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    match = request.user.matches.all()
    context = dict(user = user, match = match)  
    return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `{{profile.blabla}}` in your template but in your context, you have

```
context = dict(user = user, match = match)
```

You can only use template tags (not sure for the term) that are present in your context.

So use the right variable...

```
try:
    profile = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])


except IndexError:
    profile = None
    print(Profile.username)

except Profile.DoesNotExist:
    create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
    return redirect('profile')
```

... and put it in the context

```
context = dict(profile = profile, match = match)
```